# Removing blank cells from a Column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column with values in an Excel spreadsheet. The column contains numbers and also blank cells (by blank I mean their value is ""). Each cell contatins a formula to decide its value and will it be blank or not.

I would like to graph the column, but without the blank cells. In other words, if my column is this:

- 3
- 8
- "" (Blank Value)
- -56
- ""
- ""
- 34

I would like to convert that column to this:

- 3
- 8
- -56
- 34

So I could then graph it without the blank values.

Thanks in advance,
Michael K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a formula solution.

To get non-empty cells (cells with `""`) from `A1:A7` enter the following formula in `Cell B1` and drag/copy down as required. Change range as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$7,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$7<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$7)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROW(A1))),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. See image for reference.

[image]

Non-array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,SMALL(INDEX(($A$1:$A$9<>"")*ROW($A$1:$A$9),0),COUNTBLANK($A$1:$A$9)+ROW(A1))),"")
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @MichaelKanon - I've added non-array formula in answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use AutoFilter.

(few more characters to make answer valid)

**UPDATE:**

My first answer wasn't very complex, but AutoFilter could help here, also for making a graph. If you filter dataset of chart, it will update with visible data only. Check pictures below.

[image: Chart with empty cells]
[image: Chart with no empty cells]

Answer (score -1):

Relace all "" with an actual blank. (Either using find and replace, or an IF statement) Then follow this: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/a-quick-way-to-delete-blank-rows-in-excel/